# SAP Commerce maxHttpHeaderSize

Tags: tomcat, http-headers, sap-commerce-cloud

We are using SAP Commerce Cloud CCV2 2105, and we've had trouble recently with cookie sizes causing our customers to experience 400 Bad Request errors. We were seeing Kibana messages saying 'Request Header too large', and after submitting a ticket with SAP, they came back telling us to add the following to our cloud portal:

ccv2.platform.tomcat.serverxml.maxHttpHeaderSize=16384

After making this change, it appears to have given us a little more breathing room when it comes to the total sum of all cookie sizes.

My question is if we wanted to increase the value of this to allow even larger cookies or more cookies, what should we set it to? I can see that 16384 is a multiple of 1024, so I gather that we would want to increase it in increments of 1024. What would stop us from just doubling the size to  32768?

Answer (score 1):

**SAP CC (Hybris)** uses **Tomcat** as its application server. Therefore, the value of `ccv2.platform.tomcat.serverxml.maxHttpHeaderSize` property will set the value of `maxHttpHeaderSize` **Tomcat server** property.

The default value of [`maxHttpHeaderSize`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html)  is `8192 (8 KB)` and it can be set up to `65536 (64KB)` with no issues.

Please bear in mind other details regarding Cookies which are Browser specific.
For instance: Chrome & Firefox allow a total of `180 cookies per domain` and max size of `4096 (4KB) per cookie`.